# Muttrc: how to source a file in muttrc's directory

Tags: relative-path, mutt

I have a `muttrc` file which sources a secondary file `mutt-secrets` which resides in its same directory. But I have what appear to be two conflicting needs:

1. Be free to reference the `muttrc` file from any working directory
2. Be free to move it (and `mutt-secrets`) without having to edit `muttrc` to change the `source` path for `mutt-secrets`

At present, the first line of my `muttrc` says: `source mutt-secrets`. That works fine when I run `mutt` from within the directory where the two file reside, but if I run `mutt` from elsewhere and reference `muttrc` with a `-F` flag, then `mutt` can find `muttrc`, but `muttrc` can't find `mutt-secrets`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I've just checked it and if I understood your problem correctly you can do what you want out of the box in neomutt: https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths. For example:

```
source ~/.mutt/mutt-secrets
```

Comment: You missed point 2: `Be free to move it (and mutt-secrets) without having to edit muttrc to change the source path for mutt-secrets`

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR one-line solution:

```
source `lsof -c mutt -Fn | grep '/muttrc$' | sed 's|^n||; s|/muttrc$||;'`/mutt-secrets
```

or, if you want to reuse the `muttrc` directory, you can save it to a custom variable:

```
set my_muttrc_dir = `lsof -c mutt -Fn | grep '/muttrc$' | sed 's|^n||; s|/muttrc$||'`
source $my_muttrc_dir/mutt-secrets
```

If you want to see the output of the command when you launch `mutt`, you can put this line in your `muttrc`:

```
echo `lsof -c mutt -Fn | grep '/muttrc$' | sed 's|^n||; s|/muttrc$||'`
```

**Assumptions**: the Mutt process is called `mutt` and the Mutt's initialization file is called `muttrc`. Furthermore, you *could* get in trouble if you have more than one Mutt instance running (for example if you launch in parallel two or more Mutt instances with different initialization files, because the command may select the wrong path).

## Explanation

The idea is to look for `muttrc` full path in the list of open files by Mutt. We can get this list using `lsof` command (it has to be installed in your system), then extract the full path by parsing the `lsof` output with `grep` and `sed` commands.

This approach is viable because Mutt's initialization files support the use of external command's output with backticks (``). When Mutt encounter and execute our command enclosed in backticks (``), it is in the process of reading the `muttrc` file, so the `muttrc` file appears in the list of currently open files by Mutt. This enables us to use the `lsof` command.

### `lsof` parameters

- `-c mutt`: list open files of process named `mutt`;
- `-Fn`: for each element, print only the name (it is the path in our case). Because of `lsof` output format, the path will be prefixed with the character `n`.

### `grep` and `sed`

We use `grep` to select the line which contains `muttrc` file path, assuming the filename is exactly `muttrc`. Then we clean the `lsof` output with `sed` by both removing the `n` character at the beginning of the line and the `/muttrc` string from the end of the line. This way we get the path of the directory containing the `muttrc` file.

## There is a cleaner solution?

Mutt expands relative paths inside initialization files from its current working directory, i.e. from the directory you launch Mutt. It supports a mechanism that allows path's expansion relatives to something different, but the "initialization file directory" or something similar are not available. See [here](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#shortcuts).

I neither found a way to get the `-F <path>` option you pass to the `mutt` command inside the initialization file.

## References

- [backticks](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#ex-rc-backtick) in Mutt's initialization file;
- [current directory](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#cd);
- [_mutt_buffer_expand_path, source code](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/mutt-2-1-3-rel/muttlib.c#L476)
- [source_rc, source code](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/mutt-2-1-3-rel/init.c#L2837)
- [source_rc call, source code](https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/-/blob/mutt-2-1-3-rel/init.c#L2957)
- Tested with: Mutt 2.0.5, lsof  4.93.2, GNU grep 3.7, GNU sed 4.7.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).